# Using Eclipse CDT with the Firefox Nightly code

Tags: eclipse, firefox, environment-variables, eclipse-cdt, firefox-nightly

I downloaded Mozilla-central and built it. I am able to run Firefox Nightly using ./mach run.
Now I am following the instructions of MDN on [how to use Eclipse CDT with Mozilla code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Eclipse/Eclipse_CDT#Installing_Eclipse).
I downloaded Eclipse CDT on my mac and installed it. When I execute the following command:

> ./mach build-backend -b CppEclipse

It raises an exception saying: Failed to launch eclipse to import project. Ensure 'eclipse' is in your PATH and try again

I tried to add the eclipse's directory (Applications/Eclipse.app) to my PATH environment variable but I still get the same error.

Here is the complete trace:

> 0:00.46
>   /Users/****/src/mozilla-central/obj-ff-dbg/_virtualenvs/init/bin/python
>   /Users/****/src/mozilla-central/obj-ff-dbg/config.status --backend
>   CppEclipse Reticulating splines...  0:02.99 File already read.
>   Skipping:
>   /Users/****/src/mozilla-central/gfx/angle/targets/angle_common/moz.build
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/****/src/mozilla-central/obj-ff-dbg/config.status", line 1022,
>   in 
>       config_status(**args)   File "/Users/****/src/mozilla-central/python/mozbuild/mozbuild/config_status.py",
>   line 146, in config_status
>       the_backend.consume(definitions)   File "/Users/****/src/mozilla-central/python/mozbuild/mozbuild/backend/base.py",
>   line 143, in consume
>       self.consume_finished()   File "/Users/****/src/mozilla-central/python/mozbuild/mozbuild/backend/cpp_eclipse.py",
>   line 158, in consume_finished
>       self._import_project()   File "/Users/****/src/mozilla-central/python/mozbuild/mozbuild/backend/cpp_eclipse.py",
>   line 181, in _import_project
>       raise Exception("Failed to launch eclipse to import project. " Exception: Failed to launch eclipse to import project. Ensure
>   'eclipse' is in your PATH and try again

Also, using the command:

> ./mach ide eclipse

I again get the same message:

> Eclipse CDT 8.4 or later must be installed in your PATH. Download:
>   http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php

How can I resolve this issue?
I just need to open Firefox nightly in Eclipse to be able to get the call-graph and navigate through its source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Eclipse first, then:

1- Command:

> ps -ef |grep -i ecli

Output:

> 501  6410     1   0  2:57pm ??         0:44.98 /Applications/Eclipse
>   CPP.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse   501  6428  6365   0  2:57pm ttys001
>   0:00.00 grep -i ecli

2- Add the binary to the path:

> export PATH=/Applications/Eclipse\ CPP.app/Contents/MacOS/:$PATH

3- Test it:

> which eclipse